# Hash variable used in perl

Tags: perl, cgi

What is the meaning of this used in the CGI file

```
    my %page = ( web => \%WEB );
```

this code is written in cgi file by using perl code.

Comment: it is hash of hashes structure

Answer (score 5):

this seems to be a hash of hash in which the "web" is assigned the reference of hash "WEB" 
see the code and run it to get result

CODE:-

```
use Data::Dumper;
%WEB = ('Martin' => 28,
         'Sharon' => 35,
         'Rikke' => 29,);

my %page = ( web => \%WEB );
print Dumper (\%page);
```

RESULT:-

```
$VAR1 = {
          'web' => {
                     'Rikke' => 29,
                     'Martin' => 28,
                     'Sharon' => 35
                   }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

See [perlreftut - Mark's very short tutorial about references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for explanation. `\` returns a reference to its operand. The example would create a hash of hashes.